# SwiftUI: Why does ForEach need an ID?

Tags: swiftui

Im using a ForEach loop in my SwiftUI View and I am getting strange warnings.

It works fine like this:

```
ForEach(0..<7) { i in
    // do something
}
```

Then I changed 7 to a constant:

```
let numberOfElements = 7
ForEach(0..<numberOfElements) { i in
    // do something
}
```

And got the following warning:

> Non-constant range: argument must be an integer literal

I googled an found the following solution which works:

```
let numberOfElements = 7
ForEach(0..<numberOfElements, id:\.self) { i in
    // do something
}
```

However, I have no idea why it works. Why do I have to give an ID to the ForEach loop, and what is the ID for?

Comment: Interestingly, the warning disappears if you wrap it in, for example, a `VStack`.

Comment: FWIW, the presence of `id` parameter resolves to a different initializer, e.g. [`init(_:id:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:id:content:)-82hm4) versus [`init(_:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-6db7u).

Answer (score 4):

```
ForEach(0..<numberOfElements) { i in
    // do something
}
```

The reason why using the above `ForEach` init pops the using literal value warning is because SwiftUI doesn't expect to re-render anything when using the `Range<Int>` init method. [This is a documented requirement / feature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-6db7u). The exceptions are the init methods with `id:`.

A hashable `id` matters in SwiftUI as well as in many other view-tree based frameworks like React is because these UI frameworks needs to use these `id`s to track updates for views inside the `ForEach` or any other "Container Views", to help the framework achieve usable performance. If you want to dig deeper, take a look at this [WWDC video: Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022).